# Accessing JSON array in react native returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

so I have the following JSON returned from a server: (lets call it userData)

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "code": "SSO2000000",
  "data": [
      {
        "serial": "1468235077022",
        "pairing": null,
        "status": "ACCEPTED",
        "field_timestamp": "20-10-2017 09:13:07",
        "server_timestamp": "20-10-2017 09:13:08",
        "source": null,
        "destination": null,
        "source_warehouse": null,
        "destination_warehouse": "0201 - Palembang - GWH",
        "product_id": "0000066",
        "product_name": "ONU BDCOM P1004C1",
        "location_name": null,
        "reason": null,
        "covered_by": null,
        "wo_no": null,
        "wo_description": null
      }
  ]
}
```

I have read that the way to access "status" here is by doing `userData.data[0].status` or `userData['data'][0]['status']`.

but both is returning undefined for me.
does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: working fine for me

Comment: Are you parsing the JSON into an object with `JSON.parse(userData)`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad! lol I forgot to consider that in my app userData may be null depending on the state and it is accessed by render().

So what I did was just store userData.data in a variable first then check if its undefined. only when its not undefined I proceed with accessing data[0].status

sorry for the confusion guys!